# Rails 3 - unserialize returns only ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute

Tags: ruby, activerecord, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently upgraded an old `Rails 2.3` app (Ruby 1.8.7) to `Rails 3.2 / Ruby 1.9.3`. When using ActiveRecord serialize and trying to access a serialized attribute, i get:

```
 ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute returned.
 .unserialize then returns the actual value.
```

The real strange thing is, that there a some models which have a normal behavior.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now figured out when this problem happens, but i still dont know why:

This works:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :options, Hash
end
```

Options return {}

If i call the model itself before serialize, like that:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  USER_LIST = User.all.map {|u| [u.name, u.id]}

  serialize :options, Hash
end
```

i get ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Confirmed that calling serialize at the top of the model definition may be required

Comment: I got burned by this too. To clarify, it appears that `serialize` doesn't have to be the first line under the class declaration, but it does have to get called before something else in the model invokes an ActiveRecord call.

Answer (score 1):

Try using unserialized_value rather than unserialize, so it doesn't matter whether or not it has already been unserialized. For reference, view the source for the unserialized_value method here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/Attribute.html

Comment: the solution of this problem is easy, is still dont understand WHY it happens....